# выпавшие значения спинера копировать в другую область

Tags: vba

посмотрел в Ютубе у "цифровая академия" как сделать несколько спинеров, открыл повер поинт и сделал в нем три спинера, все крутятся/останавливаются по триггеру, теперь для полного счастья не хватает знаний сделать чтобы:выпавшие значения копировались в определенное место, выставить галочки чтобы спиннеры крутились не все вместе а лишь те которые выбрал, заранее спасибо тем кто откликнется на мольбу о помощи.